# Media query help for laptop screens

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Am using media query for the laptop screens:
@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px) and (max-width: 1366px){}

Now for Macbook pro 1224px aligns everything on website perfectly. But the 1366px for other laptop screens, am unable to fix the alignment issues, as 1366px is part of the @media.

I tried having 1224px and 1366px as two separate media query and had all the css under it, but it seems only 1366px works.

What should i do to make work both resolutions, so that the website looks fine on both resolutions?

Comment: i wouldn't suggest designing for specific viewports in the first place. just use 3 major breakpoints (<1200px / <992px / <768px) all other stuff should be fluid and then you can go ahead and use a grid-system for rows and cols.

Comment: @Dustin:Thank you, i will use them.